How do you import libraries so you can use coloured text while using an online IDE with Python?
I am using an online IDE: www.online-ide.com or replit.com make a text based dungeon game. I am trying to use coloured text to make things clearer with the combat system but cannot work out how to. I have tried using pip install termcolour in the shell tab and have tried in both IDEs code such as:
print('\033[31mHello World but Red!\033[0m')

# Print text with a blue background
print('\033[44mHello World but on Blue!\033[0m')

# Print text in red with a blue background
print('\033[31m\033[44mHello World but Red on Blue!\033[0m')

but it doesn't print coloured text, what is the simplest way to make coloured text (without libraries if possible)?

Use a terminal that supports printing in color...

Python (and pretty much any language) doesn't have color. As your own snipped illustrates, when you print in red in the console, you don't really "print in red". You just send to the console some special chars to print that the console (the terminal emulator) interpret as meaning "use a color". Exactly as it is up to the terminal to decide what to do when they receive byte 48 (most of them print a round shape to symbolize zero), 49 (most of them print a vertical bar, that is 1), etc (of course using a standard convention, namely ascii), it is up to each terminal to decide what to do with

non-printable chars, including "control sequences". Some (VT100 was for a long time a de facto standard, and lot of terminals branded themselves as "VT100 compatible") use the control sequences now known as ANSI control sequences. And most terminal emulator of nowadays emulates that behaviour.

But if they don't, there is nothing you can do from python. All python can do is send some bytes to the terminal and hope it will know what to do with it. Any module than handle colors is just a high level library that adds the \033[31m for you and hope it works (I reduce their role a bit too much. They can also try to figure out, from environment, what kind of control sequence the terminal understand, to switch to some other standard, since there are many, if needed. But nowadays, virtual terminals either understand ANSI sequence — \033[... and the like — or nothing)
